# What is wrong with printing sizeof(char) and sizeof("a")?

Tags: c, char, sizeof

The sizeof(char) in C gives 1 and sizeof("a") gives 2. Please help

Comment: `"a"` is a string literal and has the type `char[2]`?

Comment: "a" is null terminated, i.e. a+null = 2?

Comment: Just always remeber, that `a` because of double quotes is a  `String literal`. In `C`  `String literal` is `char []` so next time you ask your self something like this think of that.

Comment: Note too that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so there is no point using it. But it is good to use when you have for example `char a;` and then you can use `sizeof a` to protect against errors if you should later change `char a;` to `int a;`.

Comment: @Michi: Although not explicitly stated, a _string literal_ should be seen as `const char []` actually. This follows from writing to it being undefined behaviour, as for other `const` variables. IMO the standard does not state this clearly is some legacy and for compatibility when converting to a `char *`. Especially the latter is still common usage to set a default "string" for a pointer (questionable but useful).

Comment: @Olaf Sir, yes you right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sizeof("a")
```

`"a"` is a string that reads `{'a','\0'}`, which is 2 chars, or 2 bytes. This is because in C, double quotes indicate a string. A string in C is required to be null-terminated.

```
sizeof(char)
```

a single character is guaranteed to have the size 1 byte.

Answer (score 6):

A `char` i.e. a character has size 1.

The *string literal* `"a"` is ***not*** a character. It is a "string" (and by string I mean `char[]`). All "strings" in C are null-terminated, so your "string" is actually:

```
{'a','\0'}
```

And that's two characters. So size is 2.

Answer (score 3):

A  `sizeof(char)`  is **1 byte** of **size**, where as **"a"** is a **string** which having 1byte for character and it will end with null **'\0'**, so `sizeof("a")` is **2 byte**.

Comment: Please put some text formatting and indent and format the code in your answer.

Comment: @Magisch : For understanding we need brain not format .

Comment: Format is still better then no format, and a future user coming across this might misunderstand it based on lack of format.

Answer (score 2):

'a' is not the same as "a"

at least for 8-bit CPUs like AVRs:

'a' is a single char and

```
sizeof('a') == 1,
```

the answer you expected.

"a" is a string as noted in the other answers.

Comment: On my 32-bit computer `sizeof('a')` is 4.

Comment: 'a' is considered an integer literal, or implementation dependant. Either way, on most computers `'a' == 97` and sizeof(97) is dependant on your implementation, but usually 4.

Comment: `sizeof 'a'` yields different results in C and C++. [In C](http://ideone.com/Zigqvx) is it the same as `sizeof (int)` and [in C++](http://ideone.com/taoNnT) it is the same as `sizeof (char)`.

Comment: Everything you comment destroys a good Answer. There is No `c++` tag, so please don't mention it.  And if `'a' is considered an integer literal` You mean that saying that `'a' is a single char` is wrong?

Comment: @pmg This question is solely tagged with "c", so the c++ interpretation is close to irrelevant.

Comment: @Michi, Magisch: After the first comments, Georg edited his answer but left the error in, so I guess he is validating his answer with a C++ compiler. Basically, this answer is wrong.

Comment: Based at the moment, where the Question is given, the Answer, so as it is now...i don't think that is wrong. Please explain. I didn't saw the first one.

Comment: The sentence "'a' is a single char" although correct induces in error. The type of `'a'` (in C) is `int`; in most implementations `sizeof (int)` yields `4`.

Comment: @Michi `sizeof('a') == 1,` is false on a C compiler. On a C compiler, `sizeof('a')` evaluates to 4, since `'a'` is considered an integer literal.

Comment: @Magisch Yes, you right. i ignored the part with `sizeof('a') == 1` and i was thinking that he refered to `sizeof(char) == 1`

Comment: @pmg Sir, I'm sorry i wasn't paying attention to that. I thought that he referred to `sizeof(char)`. My bad :)